# C Brute Force recursive function

Tags: c, recursion, brute-force

So im having trouble working with recursive functions, my problem is that i have an array that represents golden coins which is a[] this array has coins that need to be shared with two users with a way that every user in the long run gets the same amount of gold or the best solution ... like this

```
Gold
10 6 5 2
User A : gets 10 2
User B : gets 6 5
```

The absolute value between User A and User B give me the diference.
In this case it would be 1

To solve this problem i need to get through all possible combinations avaiable thats why i use bruteforce and a recursive function ... To do this i have to run every single combination and see the absolute difference between the two if its better than previous ones i save it in the global variable best ...

The problem is the function isnt working good at all.. if you help me i would be appreciated ...

The code is below:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int best = 0; // keeps the best option



int share_friends_recursive(int nelems,int a[],int friend_a,int friend_b,int i){
    int sub = 0;
    friend_a += a[i];
    friend_b += a[i+1];
    if(i+1 == nelems){

        return 0;
    }else{
        sub = abs(friend_a - friend_b);
        if(sub < best){
            best = sub;
        }
        i++;
        share_friends_recursive(nelems,a,friend_a,friend_b,i);
    }

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    //
    int nelems = 4;
    int a[] = {10,6,5,2};



    //friend A can get the first value
    // friend B gets the second one ...
    share_friends_recursive(nelems,a,0,1,0);
    printf("%d \n",best);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please give an example or description of what ' isnt working good at all' means.

Comment: `int a[] = {'10','6','5','2'};` Did you mean to specify ASCII values?

Comment: i ment integers ... not ascii values. When i ment its not working its not getting the right solution that it should be 1 not 0 ... also it has some kind of problem i dont seem to understand in a recursive way. im kinda blocked at this problem...

Comment: instead being rude and giving bad rep why dont you do something constructive and helpful since this is why this exists otherwise just do something else ...

Comment: Well for one, change `int a[] = {'10','6','5','2'};` to `int a[] = {10, 6, 5, 2};`

Comment: i notice that thanks to you ...still gives a bad result

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009146/splitting-values-into-groups-evenly

Comment: thats not a answer to my problem ..thanks anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to think about what you are doing.  For example:

```
int share_friends_recursive(int nelems,int a[],int friend_a,int friend_b,int i){
    int sub = 0;
    friend_a += a[i];
    friend_b += a[i+1];
```

So you're giving the first pile to firend A and the second to friend B.  But you're later going to recurse with `i` incremented by 1, so you're going to give the second pile to A even though you've already given it to B.  This makes no sense.

What you want to do is to try giving the first pile to A then recurse giving out the rest of the piles, then start over, try giving the first pile to B and recurse giving out the rest of the piles and compare those two cases to see which is best.

**edit**

Ok, lets go through this step by step.  You have your recursive function:

```
int share_friends_recursive(int nelems,int a[],int friend_a,int friend_b,int i){
```

here `nelems` is the total number of piles, `a` is the size of each pile, `i` is how many piles have already been distributed, and `friend_a` and `friend_b` is how much has been given to each friend.  So first, what if we've distributed all the piles?  How good a solution is this?  The caller needs to know that, so we'll return it.

```
    if (i == nelems) {
        return abs(friend_a - friend_b);
```

that tells us how good (or how poorly) we've done when we're done.  What if we're not done?  Well, then we need to try giving pile `i` to both a and b and see which is better.

```
    } else {
        int toA = share_friends_recursive(nelems, a, friend_a + a[i], friend_b, i+1);
        int toB = share_friends_recursive(nelems, a, friend_a, friend_b + a[i], i+1);
```

So which of these was better?  well, we just compare and return the lower one:

```
        if (toA <= toB)
            return toA;
        else
            return toB;
    }
}
```

..and that tells us how good the best split is.

Comment: Thanks for the answer it help me a little .. still right now i cant find how to do it since if i call two times for each friend in the recursive way how am i gonna keep track of the elements that are already distributed ...i really apreciate if you can help me ..

Comment: can anyone help me i really cant find the solution to this ... thanks

Comment: Thanks for your time ... im understading it now thanks to you ... im gonna try to do more problems of these so i can understand it better ...

Comment: For some reason it returns 0 which isnt the correct answer in this case ... im trying to see the error ...